# NHibernate & NET Persistence API not working in test project

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nunit, persistence

I am getting following error while creating EntityManager in my Data Access Layer(DAL) (Class Library project):

File name: 'Iesi.Collections, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' ---> System.NotSupportedException: An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.

I am getting this error from my TestProject (Class Library project) where I have return NUnit test cases.

I have one web application which also calls DAL, but during this call it is able to create EntityManager properly.
Actually I need to add following lines to config files which avoids the above error:

```
<runtime>
        <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
</runtime>
```

Now the problem is, I have obviously added these lines to my web.config, and that is I am able to create EntityManager. But how can I add this lines to my TestProject (which is a Console Library), because it will not have a config file associated with it.

PS: I am using NHibernate and NET Persistence API.

Comment: It seems this question has more to do with your unit testing framework than with NHibernate (and is thus missing some tag). You need to figure out how your test framework can be configure for this. On the other hand, are you loading the assembly from a network source?

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the Iesi.Collections in the bin directory, the easiest way is to add a reference in your test project.